# Set background images loaded from disk

Tags: image, qt, background

I would like change the QFrame Background at runtime, but, i would load the background from disk(an image).
Setting stylesheet at QFrame not work's, because image isn't in resources.

One way is set a QPushButton icon, for example:

```
QPixmap img("/images/01.png");
ui.pushButton->setIcon(QIcon(img));
```

But, an QPushButton isn't useful to me. I need to put other things inside of QFrame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understood in your question, you do not want to use Resources ?
If that is the case, you could do something like:

```
ui->frame->setFrameStyle(QFrame::StyledPanel);
ui->frame->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(C:/test.jpg)");
```

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was looking for.
I did not know that backgrounds can be applied in this way.

Tkanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could also try something like this:

```
QPalette pal;
pal.setBrush( ui.frame->backgroundRole(), QBrush( QImage( "/images/01.png" ) ) );
ui.frame->setPalette( pal );
```